# Can I weave aspect into same maven module it was defined in and into a 3rd party dependency?

Tags: maven, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I have a multimodule maven project with the following setup of relevant modules:

- root

  - commons-app

    - backend
    - frontend

Module frontend is built into war and deployed on Tomcat. Module backend is a standard Java application packaged as jar. All I am trying to accomplish is to make the following aspect work (in both frontend and backend):

```
@Aspect
public class VirtuosoSequenceSanitizerAspect {

    @Around("execution(* cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.facade.*Facade.save(..))")
    public Object sanitizeSequenceOnSave(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        // ... some code
    }

    @Before("execution(* org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.assignSequenceNumber(java.lang.Object, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession))")
    public void rememberAssignSequence(JoinPoint jp) {
        // .. some code
    }
}
```

This aspect is setup as a Spring bean in commons-app-context.xml like so:

```
<!-- enable aspects -->
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<!-- Aspect for fixing corrupted database sequences. -->
<bean id="sequenceAspect" class="cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.dao.VirtuosoSequenceSanitizerAspect" />
```

With this setup the around advice is working properly, however the before advice is not triggered. From what I found I concluded I need to use aspectj-maven-plugin to weave to 3rd party libs. So I added the plugin into the pom.xml for commons-app module like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <!-- Weave EclipseLink dependency -->
        <weaveDependencies>
            <weaveDependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            </weaveDependency>
        </weaveDependencies>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

With this plugin before advice works, but around advice stops working. I have been struggling to set this up correctly so both advices work as expected, but to no avail. When building commons-app module log says both advices are woven:

```
--- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.5:compile (default) @ commons-app ---
Join point 'method-execution(void cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.facade.ScheduleFacade.save(cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.scheduling.Schedule))' in Type 'cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.facade.ScheduleFacade' (ScheduleFacade.java:127) advised by around advice from 'cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.dao.VirtuosoSequenceSanitizerAspect' (VirtuosoSequenceSanitizerAspect.java:90)
Join point 'method-execution(void cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.facade.DPUFacade.save(cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.dpu.DPUTemplateRecord))' in Type 'cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.facade.DPUFacade' (DPUFacade.java:123) advised by around advice from 'cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.dao.VirtuosoSequenceSanitizerAspect' (VirtuosoSequenceSanitizerAspect.java:90)
Join point 'method-execution(void cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.facade.DPUFacade.save(cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.dpu.DPUInstanceRecord))' in Type 'cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.facade.DPUFacade' (DPUFacade.java:185) advised by around advice from 'cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.dao.VirtuosoSequenceSanitizerAspect' (VirtuosoSequenceSanitizerAspect.java:90)
Join point 'method-execution(void cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.facade.PipelineFacade.save(cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.pipeline.Pipeline))' in Type 'cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.facade.PipelineFacade' (PipelineFacade.java:134) advised by around advice from 'cz.cuni.mff.xrg.odcs.commons.app.dao.VirtuosoSequenceSanitizerAspect' (VirtuosoSequenceSanitizerAspect.java:90)
...
```

However, when I deploy frontend to Tomcat, only the before advice is triggered. How can I configure maven to always weave both advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, I actually found out, that the around advice **is** being triggered. I did not see this because the code did not do what I expected. Also, I thought it is not triggered because a debugger breakpoint was not hit. From a brief googling I found the reason...

> If around advice is inlined, the debugger can't figure out what to do
>   (we still have some JSR 45 related work to do in this area, and
>   possibly so does the Eclipse debugger). To debug around advice, you
>   also need to go to the project properties and turn off the "inline
>   around advice" AspectJ compiler option. Debugging should then
>   hopefully work as expected...